# What's the difference between sense and point?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-choice

Is it correct to say

> There is only beauty, that makes the sense/point in this world.

?

Comment: When old age shall this generation waste,
    Thou shalt remain, in midst of other woe
    Than ours, a friend to man, to whom thou sayst,
    "Beauty is truth, truth beauty," – that is all
    Ye know on earth, and all ye need to know.

Answer (score 3):

> There is only beauty, that **makes the sense** in this world.
>   There is only beauty, that **makes the point** in this world.

Before we address your explicit question, we need to fix a grammatical error. As it stands your sentence has three possible interpretations, none of which is quite what you actually say:

1. If *that* is a demonstrative pronoun, then what follows it is an independent clause whose subject is *that*. In that case you have two independent clauses, and formal use requires that the comma should be replaced with a full stop, dash or semicolon.

   > There is only beauty. That makes X in this world.

   This could be paraphrased

   > Only beauty exists. That fact makes X in this world.
2. If on the other hand *that* is a relative pronoun, then the comma marks what follows as a non-restrictive relative clause. But *that* is not permitted to start a non-restrictive clause. You have two choices:

   - You may keep this as a non-restrictive clause by replacing *that* with *which*

     > There is only beauty, which makes X in this world.

     This could be paraphrased

     > Only beauty exists, and beauty makes X in this world.
   - Or you may delete the comma and make the *that* clause a restrictive clause:

     > There is only beauty that makes X in this world.

     This may be paraphrased

     > The sort of beauty that makes X in this world is the only thing that exists.
3. I suspect, however, that neither of these is what you mean, and what you are trying to say is this

   > The only thing that makes X in this world is beauty.

   If that is the case then you should not use the existential construction, *There BE*, but the cleft construction *It BE*

   > **It is only beauty that makes X in this world.**

Now we're ready to ask what *X* should be—*point* or *sense*.

In the construction *make a **point*** the word *point* means a fact or opinion, and to *make a point* means to introduce that fact or opinion into the discourse.

> I would have asked John to meet the new client, but Susan made the point that all his time is tied up with the Osborne project.

What you probably mean is *make **sense***, which means "be meaningful or rational".

> John's proposal makes sense; let's do this his way.
>   **It is only beauty that makes sense in this world.** = *Beauty is the only thing in this world that is meaningful.*

It is also possible that you mean *make sense **of*** rather than ***in*** this world: to make sense ***of*** the world means to furnish a meaningful or rational understanding of the world.

> **It is only beauty that makes sense of this world.** = *Beauty is the only thing which makes this world understandable.*

Note that this is bare *sense*, without the article; ***the*** sense has two or three different meanings, none of which is applicable here.

Answer (score 1):

> There is only beauty that makes <del>the</del> sense in this world.

*sense* refers to one's comprehension or awareness of the world around them.

> There is only beauty that makes the point in this world.

This is grammatically acceptable, but doesn't make sense without knowing what "the point" is.